# TextArea FXML border radius

Tags: fxml, jtextarea

I'm rounding the borders of my TextArea, but there's a white background behind it, even though it shouldn't be there. How can I remove it?

```
<AnchorPane style="-fx-background-color: yellow;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17.0.2-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.example.demo.HelloController">
    <AnchorPane style="-fx-background-color: black;">
        <TextArea fx:id="terminal" prefHeight="610.0" prefWidth="600.0" wrapText="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
    </AnchorPane>
</AnchorPane>
```

My css

```
#terminal .content, #terminal{
     -fx-background-color: red;
     -fx-background-radius: 100;
     -fx-text-fill: black;

}
```

But in the end this
[happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1lZt.png)